# how to code Put Images in View with the help of Localization?

Tags: iphone

How to Code for put Images in View with the Help of Localization in iphone?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend u to download the book 
beginning iphone development exploring the iphone sdk by dave Mark, jeff lamarche 
and  read chapter 17.
and after reading this chp in 15 min u will know each and every thing about localization.